# Pass JSON data from template to django view

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-views

i have atribute value in my table with CHAR data type.

i want to post string data from html template that i got from HTTP get which i use angularjs.

When i clicked button submit i got the error

```
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:''`
```

or

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'undefined:undefined'
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="form-group" id="location">
                          <label >Location {{l.location_name}}</label>


                          <select class="form-control" ng-model="l.location_name" id="location_name" name="location_name">
                            <option ng-repeat="l in LocationList track by l.location_name" value='{{l.location_name}}'>{{l.location_name}}</option>
                          </select>
                       </div>
```

and i try to print the value in my view.py

```
print form.cleaned_data['location_name'] + "--> LOCATION NAME"
```

The Result:

```
? string:LONDON ?--> LOCATION NAME
```

Comment: Looks like conversion error, something somewhere expects an int and gets "undefined:undefined". If you post your full error traceback we might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your form is expecting a int, you're passing a string.